# Including innermost contour in an Image to find its centre

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("pcb.jpg")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(hierarchy)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    #epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    #approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"] if M["m00"] != 0 else 1)
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"] if M["m00"] != 0 else 1)
    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 3, (0, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow("Out", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This program, is used to take an input image, and then finds the centers of all shapes, detected in the image. I am trying to run this such that it would only find the centers of the innermost features. But, I'm a bit stuck here. You can take outer contours alone into consideration by changing RETR_TREE -> RETR_EXTERNAL. What what do we to retrieve innermost contours?

First I have found all the contours in the image using OpenCV built-in methods. Then, each Contour is approximated to a polygon shape. Then, its respective center is found and marked on the image.

Comment: I distinctly remember reading this very question yesterday. I also remember that people commented, suggesting solutions. where are those comments?

Comment: Maybe you're a little mistaken. I posted this yesterday. could you suggest me some solution

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I noticed much later that for some reason I wrote 0 instead of -1, deleted it... and I guess forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import cv2

image = cv2.imread("pcb.jpg") gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) hierarchy = hierarchy[0] print(hierarchy) for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    #epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    #approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
    if len(approx) == 3 or len(approx) == 4:
        continue
    if hierarchy[i][2] != -1:
        continue
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"] if M["m00"] != 0 else 1)
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"] if M["m00"] != 0 else 1)   # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 3, (0, 0, 0), -1) cv2.imshow("Out", image) cv2.waitKey()
```

I've changed my code into something like this. It just makes sure that it has no more contour as its successor in its hierarchy. But I'm quite unsure if it really is the solution. Could you figure this out and tell me where I'm wrong

Comment: Your reasoning is sound -- the innermost contours will have no children (i.e. further contours inside them).